# change (lack of) user input to default string value

Tags: python, variables

This is probably a straight forward question but I don't have the Python fundamentals down yet (running before walking)

I want user inputs for the following (coordinate) variables:

```py
source_x = input('enter blast x: ')
source_y = input('enter blast y: ')
source_z = input('enter blast z: ')
receiver_x = input('enter receiver x: ')
receiver_y = input('enter receiver y: ')
receiver_z = input('enter receiver z: ')
```

When the user input is <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the `z` coordinate (or any other), the following error arises:

```py
    source_z = float(source_z)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

I understand the error, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> input was seen as a string, but is there a quick way to identify and convert the <kbd>Enter</kbd> input to (e.g.) a `0`?

Just in case I want to undertake bulk imports and not stop my calculations further down the code.

kind regards

Comment: `Enter` is not part of this string. Problem is not `Enter` but empty string - try `float("")` and you get the same error. You can use `try/except` to catch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to check the input value to see if it is composed of digits and then cast it to the desired type or assign a default value else:

```py
import re

is_number = re.compile(r'^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$')

src_x = input('enter blast x: ')
src_y = input('enter blast y: ')
src_z = input('enter blast z: ')

rcv_x = input('enter receiver x: ')
rcv_y = input('enter receiver y: ')
rcv_z = input('enter receiver z: ')

src_x = float(src_x) if is_number.match(src_x) else 0
src_y = float(src_y) if is_number.match(src_y) else 0
src_z = float(src_z) if is_number.match(src_z) else 0

rcv_x = float(rcv_x) if is_number.match(rcv_x) else 0
rcv_y = float(rcv_y) if is_number.match(rcv_y) else 0
rcv_z = float(rcv_z) if is_number.match(rcv_z) else 0
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks, you threw me a little curveball though is_digit = isdigit. Took me a while to figure that one out :-)

Comment: @Zoner, you're right. Sorry for that. I will amend my answer. I answered another question using `pathlib` and its methods are all `is_*()`. My bad.

Comment: Just realized those values can receive floats as inputs so the solution needs a little modification (because `+`, `-`, and `.` are not `isdigit()`). I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Input always returns a string. You could do variable = int(number inputted).

Also, just use a try/except statement and assign a default value in the except clause
>
    Try:
        Num1 = int(input("Enter a number"))
        #mathematical function or whatever
    Except Exception as e:
        Num1=int(10) #or whatever default number
        print(e) #for troubleshooting

Comment: Mine would work too im pretty sure but gotta say I'm impressed with the is_digit. Forgot about that

Comment: Could just put the input in the try clause. That'd work

Comment: If you hit enter, it'd go to the except and assign a default number to the variable. What am I missing?

Comment: except statement would make perfect sense, but I never knew it existed until you mentioned it, thanks for that lesson!